# How to execute gnu octave commands inside a shell script

Tags: octave

format of final.txt mind the spacing
[image: format of final.txt]

I am trying to create a pie graph in gnu octave but i want it to run through a script file

i tried using

```
octave -persist<< EOF
[a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18] = textread( 'final.txt', '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f ' ,'delimiter', ' ' ,1 );
pie([a1(2,1),a2(2,1),a3(2,1),a4(2,1),a5(2,1),a6(2,1),a7(2,1),a8(2,1),a9(2,1),a10(2,1),a11(2,1),a12(2,1),a13(2,1),a14(2,1),a15(2,1),a16(2,1),a17(2,1),a18(2,1)],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],{"200","201","202","203","204","301","302","303","304","400","401","402","403","404","500","501","502","503"});
title(a0(2,1));
legend("200","201","202","203","204","301","302","303","304","400","401","402","403","404","500","501","502","503");    
EOF
```

The above command work when i use them directly on octave command line

but i don't get any graph when i try to run through a script file

final.txt contents

```
VMinstance  200 201 202 203 204 301 302 303 304 400 401 402 403 404 500 501 502 503
dadamfl3w6v 683 0   0   0   0   0   1   0   669 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
92ssadz9qpq 41  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
agcrarrcbqg 38  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12t2bg6ws1j 25  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
gpusa121zdz 21  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5520    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
dsad8urz24d 3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
fggfbjrfkix 253 0   0   0   0   0   4   0   957 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
fqlie42dsxj 5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   49  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
cbkajsbcj44 5   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
f4444fffffa 3968    0   0   0   0   0   4   0   3742    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

my output after textread on comandline

```
a0 =
{
[1,1] = VMinstance
[2,1] = dadamfl3w6v
[3,1] = 92ssadz9qpq
[4,1] = agcrarrcbqg
```

Comment: You should always create a MCVE. What you've included isn't minimalistic yet complete or verifiable because 'final.txt' is missing. I guess the graph pops up and closes immediately because the param is "--persistent" and doesn't work when reading from stdin. Perhaps you want to create an image with `print`, who knows?

Comment: final .txt is just a text file

Comment: its --persist but it doesn't work it just open the octave console

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code with the final.txt file you've given, there are a lot of NaNs in the values that readtxt outputs. For example, `a1` is entirely NaNs. Usually in Matlab/Octave, it is not a good idea to read the files like you do. I think you should remove the text in the first columun of your final.txt file, to obtain

```
  200   201   202   203   204   301   302   303   304   400   401   402   403   404   500   501   502   503
  683     0     0     0     0     0     1     0   669     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Then, you just load it in a matrix `A` using

```
A=load("final.txt")
```

and use the appropriate indexation.

**Edit:**

Here is the ouptut I get when I run your code from the command line:

```
>> [a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18]=textread( 'final.txt','%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f ' ,'delimiter', ' ' ,1 );

>>a1 =

 200
 NaN
 NaN
 NaN
```

Anyway, even if it works for you, what you are doing is just very bad practice. By using this c-style loading, you lose the abstraction, higher level flexibility, parallelisation and even nice syntax that matlab/octave have to offer.

Additionally, if you want to know to what type of data some row corresponds, just add a column to that row specifying and index into some dictionnary with your datatypes.

Comment: No it works fine when i run the command directly on octave command line
For that purpose i have used text read because in textread i can define what type of data is present in each column and it will read according to it

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, I added an output example to the answer.

Comment: my output

a0 =
{
  [1,1] = VMinstance
  [2,1] = aewa9hqmfl3w6v
  [3,1] = afa92sz9qpqsib
  [4,1] = agcrfgptrrcbqg
  [5,1] = ai15ut2bg6ws1j
  [6,1] = aipusasoggyhdz
  [7,1] = anotud8urzw0rm

Comment: do you have any data in final txt

Comment: I copy-pasted the two rows you'd given into a "final.txt", and executed your code.  As you see, it reads the 200 so it at least does one thing correctly... Anyway, I can't reproduce your results so I can't do more than reiterate my rant about using "load" with a dictrionnary instead of your loading style :p

Comment: now try i have copied some more rows into the final.txt

Comment: all the columns are properly spaced in the original file pls when you copy the contents of the final.txt equally space out everyting or else it will prompt an error when a opy from my file to the website the formatting is disturbed